# How to know if a Python package requires OS libraries?

Tags: python, package, dependencies

Kind of new to Python, I figured out that using mysqlclient in Python (requirements.txt) requires installed OS libraries. How can I know about these dependencies? Is there a way to list dependencies on OS libs? Thank you

I hoped to have pip or other package managers to list OS dependencies

Comment: On my experience, usually you will get the error about missing .dll or .so libraries. And using Linux also usually is much easier, because most of the missing libraries can be installed just by apt/yum, but for windows it requires some skill in compilation from the source.

Comment: on Windows some packages are better installed as pre-compiled (e.g. from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) than through pip

Comment: but anyway, there may be some specific dependencies that you need in your system. This should be documented by the package creator